# open same session in browser if its not timed out

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am using jdeveloper 11gR2 and i am developing an application in which user logs in to see the contents and when he clicks on logout session invalidates.

I want to keep track of the sessions and if the session is not invalid and user opens the application in a new tab of the same browser,then the same session sholud be initiated.

Any workaround please.

Thanks

Comment: actually i know something about session means how to create and invalidate but dont know how to retain the session.couldn't got any idea how to do it???any suggestions or any code snippets or any references plz.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour? The session cookie should be available to all tabs in a browser session. Or are you passing the session in the URL rather than via a cookie?

Comment: I agree with @AlexPoole this is the default behavior, but if you want to keep track, you could always create a listener that listen to sessions being destroyed and created for you...Check this url: http://www.javatpoint.com/Event-and-Listener-in-Servlet